# Shocking but not surprising

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

I came across this phrase on a news website:

> "It is shocking but not surprising," said the parliamentarian to..

and I wondered to myself if that is indeed a valid phrase in English. A google search for `Shocking but not surprising` reveals many articles and pages. The [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shocking?s=t) says shocking means `intense surprise`:

> adjective
>   1. causing intense surprise, disgust, horror, etc.

Although I can "guess" the meaning of the phrase, it does seem a bit odd. How can one be intensely surprised but not surprised at the same time?. It does seem in popular use, but is it a valid English phrase? If it is, can some one please provide a good example of the actual meaning with context?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not a phrase. People can still use their language to say things. This is shocking and surprising. A teenager has a drinking problem. He dies in a car accident while driving. It shocks you but it may not surprise you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a pedantic peeve

Comment: Is there a reason @mojoJojo, that you are discounting the 'disgust' and 'horror' elements of the definition?

Comment: @Spagirl hit it.  If you have become accustomed to person or group X doing horrible things, the next time they do a horrible thing, you may be shocked once again (if your responses have not been deadened), but not surprised. To say whether the parliamentarian in question was using the phrase in this way, or being sloppy, we need more context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Its shocking but not surprising that you'd close the question as a pedantic peeve ;-) As a non native English speaker I did find it confusing - the question has been somewhat popular though - its been viewed 10k times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say a politician who swears a lot in private suddenly uses profanity in public, for example, on a live TV interview.

A viewer might say, "It is shocking(,) but not surprising."

It could mean he is shocked to see a politician use profanity in public because it is not the right thing for any politician to do and it is unbecoming of a public figure, but he has been expecting this would happen in one day or another because he knows he swears very often in private.

Not surprising in the sentence means "it is not something that I didn't expect to happen". In other words, "it is something that I expected would happen".

Answer (score 2):

We should take that dictionary definition to mean causing intense surprise, disgust, or horror, not necessarily all of them simultaneously. That’s the take of [Merriam-Webster’s simple definition of *shocking*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shocking) (my emphasis):

> very surprising and upsetting ***or*** causing a sudden feeling of horror or disgust

So news that are shocking but not surprising are news that cause a sudden feeling of horror or disgust but were not entirely unexpected. That is not uncommon: sometime we’re counting on something bad, but it’s when it actually happens that we feel the blow.