# Word to express surprised, but not surprised

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

There are times when someone's actions are both surprising, but not surprising at the same time. Almost expected, yet still surprising.

### Example: The Scorpion and the Frog

When the [Scorpion strings the Frog in the parable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scorpion_and_the_Frog), it is both surprising and not surprising at the same time. We're surprised because the scorpion just doomed himself; but not surprised because it is in the scorpion's nature to kill his prey.

### Example: An Addict

When an addict has been clean for several years and then falls down the rabbit hole again, it is both surprising and not surprising at the same time. We're surprised because the addict has been clean for several years, but not surprised because the addict is an addict.

### Question

What is a word describing when someone is both surprised, but not surprised at the same time? Almost expected, yet still surprising.

Phrases such as *"in one's nature"* doesn't express the surprised part. Ideally, this is a word that could be used in everyday conversations:

> Joe: "Did you hear the Scorpion stung the Frog while they were
> swimming across the river and they both died?"
>
> Jane: "Really? Wow, that's surprising. I guess that's kind of
> expected, though."

Comment: I don't know about a single word to encapsulate this, but a a common saying is "shocking but not surprising," which I've heard many times. It was also discussed on this stack exchange thread: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328766/shocking-but-not-surprising  --- If I think of anything better, I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: You could use the phrase [_in retrospect_](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in--retrospect), since the realization of not being surprised usually comes after a moment of thinking back on the evidence.

Comment: I don't have a single word but some other ways of putting it in a phrase are:  "I suppose it was bound to happen", or "always out there" ('the possibility was always out there').  "hanging over ones head" .. or "we always had it hanging over our head" are others.  You're looking for more of  single word though.

Comment: 'apprised of' is frequently used when being notified of predictable yet still note-worthy events. I'm not sure the dictionary definitions support my take on the word though.  "Wow, thanks for apprising me of that."  It probably doesn't go far enough.

Comment: You are ***dismayed*** even though you have ***resigned yourself*** to the ***inevitability*** of it.

Comment: Are you looking for a term to describe the viewer's emotion or to describe the situation itself?

Comment: IMO - 1) `in retrospect` doesn't cover the former of being surprised. 2) `always out there` (and related) is a good phrase to describe a post-mortem discussion of what just happened. 3) Agreed with Tom22 `apprised of` that it doesn't go far enough. 4) `dismayed even though you have resigned yourself to the inevitability`... is a good phrase for the overall situation, looking for something shorter, though.

Comment: @Lawrence - For this particular usage, I am looking for a term (or very short phrase) describing the viewer's emotion. Where the viewer is surprised the event happened, but because of past events isn't surprised at the same time, perhaps because the event a pattern of behavior that has been normalized or similar.

Comment: @MetroSmurf In that case, what about "*d'oh!*"?

Comment: Even if you're trying to make a distinction between a general idea and a specific instance sorry, there is no such phrase, let alone single word… although of course, no-one could ever prove that.

Some kind of irony might just be involved and failing that, it's not going to happen.

Comment: I can't think of a single word; perhaps a figurative expression helps here.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that these situations are *tragic* or *ironic* but not surprising.

Irony and surprise are both characterized by something unexpected happening. Likewise, tragedy is about things that were good turning bad, usually due to some fatal character flaw (as in the scorpion or addict).

People disagree about what is or isn't ironic a lot, but to me the key thing about irony is that sense of something unexpected that actually makes a lot of sense. Whereas something surprising feels like it is coming out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

In your examples, the "surprise" is not necessarily the event itself. You are actually surprised that the actor made the choice that led to the event. This makes you feel kinda stupid, because you know you should have seen it coming.

I submit "stupefied."

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stupefied

Answer (score 0):

For situations where something surprising happened, but the actual outcome could have been seen clearly in hindsight, my family uses the phrase "oddly predictable".

> Joe: "Did you hear the Scorpion stung the Frog while they were swimming across the river and they both died?"
>
> Jane: "Really? That was oddly predictable."

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say it as

Joe: "Did you hear the Scorpion stung the Frog while they were swimming across the river? they both died!"

Jane: "Really? Wow, that's surprising. I guess that's kind of expected though, I mean, it is in their nature"

or in the first paragraph you gave I would write it as:

When the Scorpion stings the Frog in the parable, it is surprising but expected. We were shocked because the scorpion just doomed himself, but not surprised because it is in the scorpion's nature to kill their prey.

Being surprised but expecting the end result is something I personally don't use as a way for how a character should act. But