# A word or phrase to say something was in a sense unexpected yet it was only to be expected?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The uprising was —————— .

The uprising was so unexpected. Nobody would predict it. But, at the same time, in a sense it was only to be expected, because there were a lot of unsolved issues in the society that make it prone to the uprising.

Is there a word or phrase common to say about events/happenings that, in a sense, are not expected but, in another sense, really expected.

Comment: I think expressions such  as “looming ahead” or “looming on the horizon” may  convey the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't 'only to be expected' strongly connote the heedless lack of preparedness?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So? Are you saying it is sufficient by itself to convey the meaning I want?

Comment: I'd use it; to me it conveys (with the 'only') the 'but as usual no one was prepared for it' subtext: a wise comment after the event.

Comment: "Predictable, yet unexpected when it came"? I can't think of anything more succinct.

Comment: Like the tombstone inscription that said "I expected this, but not so soon".

Comment: There's always "Well, duh!!"

Comment: shocking yet inevitable

Answer (score 4):

An old expression is "I was shocked but not surprised."  It's hard to find a definitive online source, especially without political overtones.  But here are three examples:

[Yale political opinion piece](https://medicine.yale.edu/news-article/shocked-but-not-surprised/)

[facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/jeffnischwitz/photos/shocked-but-not-surprisedthis-phrase-im-shocked-but-not-surprised-has-become-one/2205851599656657/)

[gossip column](http://www.irealhousewives.com/2015/06/breaking-news-brandi-glanville-fired.html)

A quick Internet search will find dozens of other examples.  There is even a Stack Exchange question about it, but the question and most of the comments are from people unfamiliar with the expression:

[Shocking but not surprising [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328766/shocking-but-not-surprising)

The phrase is often used tongue-in-cheek, possibly because the words "shocked" and "surprised" are so close in meaning that at first it sounds like a contradiction.  A little thought and a lot of context are needed to understand it. It's often meant as jab at someone, implying that you didn't expect much from their behavior to begin with. From your example, the expression matches the meaning of "expected yet not expected," but may be a little more whimsical than what you are looking for.  I'm submitting this anyway in case it may be relevant to others who came to this page with a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a set phrase, but you could say **"The uprising was inevitable in hindsight."**

This hearkens to the so-called "hindsight bias", or the "knew-it-all-along phenomenon". It expresses the notion that even though future events may be unpredictable in the moment, they seem highly predictable and obvious when looking back in hindsight. No one could have predicted the uprising before it happened, but in hindsight, it's much simpler to isolate and identify the contributing causes, leading to the conclusion that *of course* such a thing would happen. The sense of inevitability additionally conveys the notion that even though one may be surprised by the exact moment at which something occurs, they are not surprised that it occured at some point.

The uprising cannot be both expected and unexpected simultaneously in a single moment in time. In the moment, it is not expected, but it should have been expected *in hindsight*.

Answer (score 2):

> The uprising was **hiding/hidden in plain sight.**

> **Hide in plain sight**
>
> To remain unseen despite being in full, unrestricted view.
>
> **Hidden in plain sight**
>
> Concealed or unseen despite being in full, unrestricted view.
>
> [Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hiding+in+plain+sight)

When something unseen is revealed or noticed, it may surprise you. However, if you realize it wasn't really hidden and was in plain view, you might conclude it should have been seen or expected rather than come as a surprise.

---

> The future for VR [Virtual Reality] is beyond bright—it is stunning. A
> revolution is starting, **hiding in plain sight**.
> [K. Schwab and N. Davis; *Shaping the Future of the Fourth Industrial Revolution*, p.185](https://www.google.com/search?q=athe%20future%20for%20vr%20is%20beyond%20bright%20revolution%20hiding%20in%20plain%20sight&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsb1yQJ6YVdi0RVz_Fl2lQHU2FHLnQ%3A1666820160036&ei=QKhZY9XcAfqf5NoPxtOAcA&ved=0ahUKEwjV_Kv87P76AhX6D1kFHcYpAA4Q4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=athe%20future%20for%20vr%20is%20beyond%20bright%20revolution%20hiding%20in%20plain%20sight&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQkA9YnE1g8k5oAXAAeAGAAcIBiAGvFZIBBDM0LjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (2018)

> For other women detailed in this anthology, their radicalism was
> **hidden in plain sight**. [Dayo Gore et al. *Want to Start a Revolution?*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Want_to_Start_a_Revolution/KiEUCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=revolt%20hidden%20in%20plain%20sight&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

> The answers, it turns out, were **hiding in plain sight**. During the
> two years that preceded the Declaration of Independence, Americans
> launched an insurgency that drove events toward a successful
> revolution. [Frances Kennedy et al.; *The American Revolution*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_American_Revolution/rTSTAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=revolt%20hiding%20in%20plain%20sight&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover)
> (2014)

Answer (score 1):

I think a "foreseeable" event falls somewhere between "expected" and "unexpected"...

> [**foreseeable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foreseeable)
> A foreseeable event or situation is one that can be known about or guessed before it happens

...in that if it happens, you're not surprised (it's not "unexpected"). But equally, you're not surprised if it *doesn't* happen (it wasn't "expected" either - *foresee**able*** isn't quite the same as *fore**seen***).

Answer (score 0):

This question is asking for a locution  that has to be a [contradiction in terms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contradiction%20in%20terms). The expectancy of the uprising happening can thus be categorized.

- The expectancy   of the uprising happening  was a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I rather want a contradiction in terms that has in it both being expected and being unexpected.

Answer (score -3):

Your best bets are "**improbable**" and "**controvertible**". "**Insupposable**", "**theoretical**" and "**hypothetical**" might also do. Better to do with an adjective phrase such as "Improbable yet possible", "controvertible yet plausible", "probable yet unexpected" etc.

**Hypothetical**  ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypothetical)) Based upon a hypothesis; conjectural.

**Controvertible**  ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/controvertible))  Open to questioning; that which can be denied, challenged, or disputed.